# Как создать реализацию Request.Form C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Есть метод действия который регистрирует пользователя. Что бы не засорять модель, вынес подтверждения пароля как отдельное поле в представлении. В итоге это значение получаю через `Request.Form["Повторите пароль"]`

Часть метода действия:

```
if (user.Password == Request.Form["Повторите пароль"] && ModelState.IsValid) 
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Регистрация прошла успешно! Можете логиниться";
                repository.Add_New_User(user);
                return Redirect("/Account/Login");
            }
```

И вот начал я писать тест и как мне задать вот этот `Request.Form`:

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void Registr_Error(
        {
            User testUser = new User()
            {
                LoginUser = "IlyaLogin",
                Password = "IlyaPassword"
            };

            Mock<IUsersRepository> mock = new Mock<IUsersRepository>();
            mock.Setup(m => m.Users).Returns(new User[] {
                new User { LoginUser = "Vova", Password="123123"},
                testUser
            }.AsQueryable());

            AccountController target = new AccountController(mock.Object, null);

            ViewResult result = (ViewResult)target.Registr(testUser, null);

            Assert.AreEqual("Registr", result.ViewName);
            Assert.IsFalse(result.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Mock<HttpRequestBase> request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();

 request
    .Setup(request => request.Form)
    .Returns(new FormCollection { { "Повторите пароль", "Password" } });  

 Mock<HttpContextBase> context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

 context
    .SetupGet(c => c.Request)
    .Returns(request.Object);

 Controller controller = new Controller(); // System Under Test
 controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
```

Comment: Артем, а можете дать свою почту для связи? Просто только учусь работать с MVC и я бы хотел, что бы кто то взглянул на мой мааааленький проект, так как вдруг я там столько костылей понаделал и не знаю о них...